# Find difference in last weeks data

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I'm trying to find out how much a person's views have increased in a week.

The columns I'm working with look like this.

[image]

Code to retrieve and display this data

```
<?php
  $query = "SELECT post_title, post_date, post_views_count FROM posts 
  WHERE post_user = '{$username}' AND post_status = 'published' ORDER 
  BY post_views_count DESC LIMIT 8";

  $select_views = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_views)) {
    $post_title = escape($row['post_title']);
    $post_date = escape($row['post_date']);
    $post_views_count = escape($row['post_views_count']);

    echo $post_title . ' / ' . $post_views_count . ' / ' . $post_date . 
    '<br><br>';
  }
?>
```

Returns data looking like this

[image]

Now how am I able to find the difference in how much the post_views_count increased in the past 7 days?

I'm ideally trying to echo something like "Your post has 55 more views this week"

Any direction is greatly appreciated.

Comment: how you have the info for the past weeks? ..  in you sample seems you hav only actual values

Comment: Kindly share sample data and desired output in formatted text (not images)

Answer (score 1):

Say for this week you calculated, that all the post has 0 views, then store that amount in a separate column for particular posts. And then keep on updating only the `post_views` column for a day or week, if you are trying to show the 1 week difference regularly.

Then, you can calculate the views and subtract last stored views from `post_views` to get the difference.

After calculating the difference, update the last_views columns with the `posts_views`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Best solution. Because you don't have any coloum to store views count for difference.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you wanted to do this as per post or for all posts.

This approach is for all posts.

You could find the limits for the current week (in this example from Monday to Sunday):

```
$startOfTheWeek = date("Y-m-d", strtotime('monday this week'));
$endOfTheWeek = date("Y-m-d", strtotime('sunday this week'));
```

Then running something like the following query, you get the views before the current week and during the current week:

```
SELECT SUM(viewsThisWeek) AS viewsThisWeek, SUM(viewsBeforeThisWeek) AS viewsBeforeThisWeek FROM
  (SELECT SUM(post_views_count) AS viewsThisWeek, 0 AS viewsBeforeThisWeek FROM posts AS tbl1
   WHERE post_user = '{$username}' AND (post_date BETWEEN '{$startOfTheWeek}' AND '{$endOfTheWeek}')
UNION ALL
   SELECT '0' AS viewsThisWeek, SUM(post_views_count) AS viewsBeforeThisWeek FROM posts AS tbl2
   WHERE post_user = '{$username}' AND post_date < '{$startOfTheWeek}') AS tbl3
```

After this you can easily calculate the difference in the views.

If you want to have the differences per post, then just delimit the query according to that.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a stored procedure that stores the data from past days and once the data is older then 7 days it drops that data.

This will make it so you can compare data and once the data is out of use it automatically drops it.

This will prevent your database from filling up.

Comment: Would you be able to provide some direction on this, please?